# is io.read() reading characters?

Tags: lua

```
-- print the first non-empty line
    repeat
      line = io.read()
    until line ~= ""
    print(line)
```

So, the logic is like, keep reading the characters until the next character is empty? Thanks.

Comment: `io.read()` is `file.read(io.input())`. See [`file:read`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read).

Comment: It will loop infinitely until it receives input. If ran from console it will loop till you typed in something and pressed enter. However, inside other applications most likely it will just be an infinite loop. If you are trying to get keypresses in Lua this isn't the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the comment?

```
-- print the first non-empty line
```

It prints the first non-empty line.

This is achieved by reading the input (keyboard, unless redirected) until a non-empty line has been entered. This line is then printed.

You read a line, check wether it is not an empty string `""`. If it is not, you read the next line. If it is you won't read again but print what you've read last.

Comment: what the code does is to print out the first non-empty line. My question is, what is exactly the meaning of io.read().

Comment: @kkxx that's not what you asked. you assumed it would read characters until the next one is empty. I told you what io.read() does. it reads the keyboard input until you press enter or return. the exact meaning of io.read() can be found in the Lua Manual btw

Comment: infinitely `until` the input is not an empty string. (`~=""`). Once every time you hit enter or return without entering anything else. Please read the Lua Manual. They write it to answer such questions.